# SQL simple break out by quantity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to perform a simple break out by quantity in SQL.

I have as follows:

Table name : Products

```
product    quantity
=======    ========
Car        2
Bike       1
```

Results:

```
Car
Car
Bike
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which programming language can / will you use?

Comment: this will be purely done in sql

Comment: Which flavor?  TSQL, MySql, Postgre, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to join to a table of numbers. This can repeat the row `quantity` times.  In T-SQL, a list of numbers can be generated with a recursive CTE:

```
; with  Numbers as
        (
        select  max(quantity) as nr
        from    YourTable
        union all
        select  nr - 1
        from    Numbers
        where   nr > 1
        )
select  yt.product
from    YourTable yt
join    Numbers nr
on      nr.nr <= yt.quantity
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da74a/1/0)

Comment: Thanks so much! Is Recursion heavy on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-CTE answer to show why you should use the CTE :)

**MAIN TABLE**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
      ID INT IDENTITY,
      Product VARCHAR(20),
      Quantity INT
    )
```

**OUT TABLE**

```
DECLARE @outtable TABLE
    (
      ID INT IDENTITY,
      Product VARCHAR(20)
    )
```

**TEST DATA**

```
INSERT  INTO @table
        (
          Product,
          Quantity
        )
        SELECT  'Car',
                2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Bike',
                1
```

**Main Query**

```
DECLARE @counter INT,
    @maxcounter INT,
    @curproduct INT
SELECT TOP 1
        @curproduct = id
FROM    @table 

WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1
                        1
               FROM     @table
               WHERE    ID >= @curproduct ) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @counter = 1,
                @maxcounter = quantity
        FROM    @table
        WHERE   ID = @curproduct
        WHILE @counter <= @maxcounter 
            BEGIN
                INSERT  INTO @outtable
                        (
                          Product
                        )
                        SELECT  product
                        FROM    @table
                        WHERE   id = @curproduct
                SET @counter = @counter + 1
            END
        SET @curproduct = @curproduct + 1 
    END
```

**FINALLY**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @outtable
```

Comment: Thanks so much, very kind of your for this approach!  Visitors +1 him!